# Angular 7 - Copying a List returned from SQL into an Array

Tags: angular7, asp.net-core-2.1

I would like to convert results from an SQL method to an array so that I can use the filter option on the array in Angular 7.

I am still getting my feet wet in Angular (7) and I'm trying to set up a nested dropdown/select list where the first select list is for "Departments" and the selected value will return a result set for my "DeptTypes" dropdown/select list.

I am currently returning the data by sending the selected value (id) call my "changeData(id: number)" event in the ...component.ts. It successfully returns data, but there is sometimes a problem with the dropdown not always populating. It appears that it is a performance or speed issue due to always making the call to the SQL backend. So, I would like to return the data as an array so that I can use the .filter command, but there seem to be no option for that. So, what would be the best solution to my lil' problem? I was thinking about pushing the returned list into an [] array variable that would then allow me to use "push" but I cannot figure out the coding to do that. If there is a better way, by all means, enlighten me. Thanks.

```
  // the calls in my component.ts

opportunityList() { // this is the for the first <select ...>
this.dashboardService.getOpportunities()
  .subscribe((opportunities: Opportunities) => {
    this.opportunities = opportunities;
  },
  error => {
    // this.notificationService.printErrorMessage(error);
  });
  }

  typeList(id: number) { // nested <select ...> that needs to populate
this.dashboardService.getTypesByOpportunityId(id)
  .subscribe((types: Types) => {
    this.types = types;
  },
  error => {
    // this.notificationService.printErrorMessage(error);
  });
}

changedata($event) { // called after selecting a value in the 1st <select ...>

// to remove previous selected items from second dropdown
//this.finaldata.splice(0);

// filter items and pass into finaldata
//this.finaldata = this.type2.filter(x => x.areaId == $event.target.value);
this.typeList($event.target.value);

this.finaldata = this.types;
}

// the HTML
  <label for="areaId">Departments</label>
  <select id="areaId" (change)="changedata($event)" [(ngModel)]="opportunityList" class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let opp of opportunities" [value]="opp.areaId">{{ opp.areaName }}</option>
  </select><br />
  <label for="typeId">Department Area Types</label>
  <select id="typeId" class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let typeobj of finaldata" [value]="typeobj.typeId">{{ typeobj.typeName}}</option>
  </select>
```

my ...service.ts

```
  getTypesByDepartmentId(id: number): Observable<Types> {
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('content-Type', 'application/json');
const authToken = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${authToken}`);

return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + '/dashboard/GetTypesByDepartmentId/' + id, { headers })
  .map(response => response.json())
  .catch(this.handleError);
```

}

the controller action

```
#region api/dashboard/GetTypesByDepartmentId
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task <IActionResult> GetTypesByDepartmentId([FromRoute]int id)
{
  // retrieve all revenue types

  var model = await (from t in _appDbContext.Type where t.AreaId == id 
               select new
               {
                 t.TypeId,
                 t.TypeName
               }).ToArrayAsync();
  return Ok(model);

}
#endregion
```

The code above, thru the service.ts returns the results, it is not always populating the "typeId". It's a "hit or miss." Sometimes the data is there and sometimes it's just blank.

I would like to go with returning all of the department area types and using an array and the "filter" command. for example:

```
this.finaldata = this.typeList.filter(x => x.areaId == event.target.value);
```

in the component.ts itself or a more proper way to handle this issue since "filter" does not work on this call.

Comment: I didn't think that it was necessary since I stated that I am receiving data and all I wanted to know was the best way to filter the data from the component side. I'll update my question to include the code from the service.ts and from the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I get to answer my own question. I can actually filter my returned observable ... the issue was that I was defining a variable that used an interface, reflecting my model. If I remove that and make it "any", I can then push it to an array:

```
  types: any;
  type2: Types[] = [];

  public finaldata: any[] = [];

  typeList() {
   this.dashboardService.getTypes()
  .subscribe((types: Types) => {
    this.types = types;
    this.type2.push({ areaId: this.types.areaId, typeId: this.types.typeId, typeName: this.types.typeName, areaName: this.types.areaName });
  },
  error => {
    // this.notificationService.printErrorMessage(error);
  });
 }

  changedata($event) {
// to remove previous selected items from second dropdown
this.finaldata.splice(0);


// filter items and pass into finaldata
this.finaldata = this.types.filter(x => x.areaId == $event.target.value);
}
```

So, I just call my typeList() in my "ngInit()" and it is taken care of.